# How to use the each() function to iterate through a JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I would like to show elements from a JSON file.

Here is the JSON file

```
"2015": {
"img": "<img src = \"../images/images/images_of_members/image1.jpg\">",
"img2": "<img src = \"../images/images/images_of_members/image2.jpg\">"},

"2016": {
"img": "<img src = \"../images/images/images_of_members/image1.jpg\">",
"img2": "<img src = \"../images/images/images_of_members/image2.jpg\">"  }
```

Here is the JavaScript file

```
$.ajax("gallery.json", {
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        $.each(response, function () {
            $.each(this, function (i, el) {
                $(".photo_target").css('display', 'block');
                $(".photo_target").append(el);
            });
        });
     }
});
```

Here is the HTML file

```
<div class="years">
    <p data-year="2015">Pictures 1</p>
    <p data-year="2016">Pictures 2</p>
</div>
<div class="photo_target"></div>
```

I would like to show only the pictures from the object 2015 if I click on the paragraph with attribute data-year 2015 and show pictures from object 2016 if I click on the paragraph with attribute data-year 2016. Now it is iterate through all objects and shows all pictures what can be found in this JSON file.

What should I change in the AJAX call to get it work as I want it?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `console.log` to see what your `$.each` loops are referring to?

Comment: Somewhat depends on how you want all these images loaded into page. All loaded and then filter them?...or only load the ones user wants? If there are lots of images then bandwidth may be concern for example

Comment: Will not be too many pictures and all will be optimized. Three different sizes of each picture for different screen resolution.

Comment: What I have done and work but unfortunately loads two of each pictures. Here is what I have got $.each(response, function () {
                        $.each(response[number], function (i, el) { ... } I added [number] after the response and now load only the pictures I want. But loads two pictures of each. Do you know why?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$.ajax("gallery.json", {
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (response) {
    $(".photo_target").css('display', 'block');
    for(var year in response){
      for(var key2 in response[year]){
        var $img = $(response[year][key2]);
        $img.hide();
        $img.data("year", year);
        $(".photo_target").append($img);
      }
    }
  }
});

$(".years p").click(function(){
  var year = $(this).data("year");
  $(".photo_target").find("img").hide();
  $(".photo_target").find("img[data-year='" + year + "']").show();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: How does this answer issue of filtering on click?

Comment: @charlietfl Aha, my fault. I thought the problem what to append the images as OP's original iteration didin't work. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @charlietfl I think that might work. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Hi I get error with this solution Uncaught ReferenceError: key1 is not defined

Comment: @LászlóPéterVarga Fixed!

Comment: It is still not working. No error message but does not load any picture

Comment: @LászlóPéterVarga Does is the ajax callback fired? Are the images created properly? How does the generated html code look? Does the click event fire when you click on an element? The questions are endless. No one will be able to help you if you don't start debugging the code your self. Just saying that it doesn't work wont help anyone.

Answer (score -1):

Long time I did some JQuery but you could do something similar to this:

First change your json like so*:

```
{2015 : ['/images/img1', '/images/img2'], 2016 : ['/images/img2']}
```

Then you do:

```
function fetchData(year) {
   $.ajax("gallery.json", {
     success : function(response) {
        var images = response[year];
        //images is now an array you could 'for each' over
        images.forEach(function(image) {
          //do your append...
        })

     }
   })
}
```

(*Assuming you can change the json.)

Comment: I think you missed the click part as I did. See my answer. (not the one who down voted)

Comment: Like yourself I assumed the click part was obvious and the difficulty was iterating over the images

Answer (score -1):

Here's a working solution: https://jsfiddle.net/hgmx71zt/2/

Basically I grouped all images per year in a container div:

```
for (var year in jsondata) {
  var $container = $("<div/>");
  $container
    .addClass("year-" + year)
    .appendTo($photo_target)
    .addClass("year-images");

  for (var img in jsondata[year]) {
    var $img = $(jsondata[year][img]);
    $container.append($img);
  }
}
```

I used CSS to make them hidden by default.

```
.year-images {
  display: none;
}
```

Finally, I added a click event handler that toggles the ".visible" class which makes the given container visible (again using CSS)

```
$(".years").on("click", "[data-year]", function(e) {
  var year = $(e.currentTarget).data("year"),
    container = $photo_target.find(".year-" + year);
  console.log(year);
  console.dir(container);
  container.toggleClass("visible").siblings().removeClass("visible");
});
```

The CSS for the visible class:

```
.year-images.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Hi It does not work for some reason. I do not know why and there is no error message in console at all.

Comment: The URL's in the example are fictional, so they're invisible... check out the fiddle, I didn't copy everything here.

Answer (score -2):

> $(function () {

```
$('.years p').on('click', function () {
    $(".photo_target").children().remove();
    var attr = $(this).attr('data-year');
    if (typeof attr !== typeof undefined && attr !== false) {
        var number = $(this).data('year');
        console.log(number);
        $.ajax("gallery.json", {
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                    $.each(response[number], function (i, el) {

                        $(".photo_target").css('display', 'block');

                $(".photo_target").append(el);
                    });

            }
        })

    }
})});
```

Here is my solution.
I have changed this line

```
success: function (response) {
    $.each(response, function () {
        $.each(this, function (i, el) {
            $(".photo_target").css('display', 'block');
            $(".photo_target").append(el);
```

to this

```
success: function (response) {
                    $.each(response[number], function (i, el) {
                        $(".photo_target").css('display', 'block');
                $(".photo_target").append(el);
```

It works fine now.

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: That's a really bad solution and it doesn't give any credit to the people that tried to help you. Why do you load the same data on each click, why not do it like suggested by everyone else here?

Comment: I'm sure you are a far better programmer than me. The only reason I shared my solution is that works fine for me. The others just don't. I tried all and the result is a blank field while my one load the pictures. At each click has an AJAX call what cost only 2kB data what is almost nothing. The pictures are downloaded during the first click after I think they are cached. Google Development Tools show me no picture downloading after the first click at all. Sorry if I've made you fed up.